# Keydown Eventhandler Process

Tags: c#, keydown

I am trying to process to keydown event but the below code is process only first char of string and not able to remove second char of string.

```
private void Game_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(BirdsArray[SelectedIndex].THIS_STRING.First()== (char)e.KeyData)
    {
        BirdsArray[SelectedIndex].THIS_STRING = BirdsArray[SelectedIndex].THIS_STRING.Remove(0, 1);
        this.Validate();
    }
}
```

In this below code `BirdsArray` is array of panels, `THIS_STRING` is a string type of string object in `BirdsArray`.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. What are you expecting to happen? What actually happens? Maybe post an example.

Comment: It looks as you're trying to process an exact string to be typed in. Although the current code doesn't allow restarting from the end, because the processed characters are actually removed, it should work in theory. As Evan said, more info is needed. One thing is: where is selectedindex set. Another is, to what is game_keydown attached, and is it possible that that control loses focus after the first keydown?

Comment: Your code is either wrong or your decription is or both. A Panel doesn't have a Property THIS_STRING. A string doesn't have a method First() so this should not compile let alone remove a character from anything.. And what is the Validate() supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KeyDown event gives you the *virtual* key code of the key that was pressed.  Like Keys.A if you press the A-key.  It just tells you about the key, not about the letter that's produced by the key.  Which depends on the active keyboard layout (it is not an A in Japan or Russia for example) and what modifier keys are down.  Shift being the obvious example, producing either `A` or `a`.  Or Alt which, when down, doesn't produce a letter at all.

So your code will work by accident if the first letter of the string is capitalized.  You'll run out of luck when the rest are not.  `A` does not match `a`.

It is pretty unclear to me why you need this feature.  Do consider the KeyPress event instead.  Which gives you the actual letter that the user sees on the screen.